# PHP get parameter from URL string (not current page)

Tags: php, regex, url-parameters

I know you can easily get a parameter from the page you're currently on, but can you easily do the same from any URL string?

I need to grab the "id" parameter out of a string like `https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctr.paid?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnplcHRvbGFiLmN0ci5wYWlkIl0`.

How can I do this with PHP? Is there a built-in function, or do I have to use regex?

Answer (score 4):

You could use combination of [parse_url](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url = 'https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctr.paid?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnplcHRvbGFiLmN0ci5wYWlkIl0';
$arr = parse_url($url);
parse_str($arr['query']);
echo $id; //com.zeptolab.ctr.paid?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnplcHRvbGFiLmN0ci5wYWlkIl0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

From the PHP docs:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
        [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)

/path
```

Answer (score 2):

There's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php):

```
function extractGETParams($url)
{
  $query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  $parts = explode('&', $query_str);
  $return = array();

  foreach ( $parts as $part )
  {
    $param = explode('=', $part);
    $return[$param[0]] = $param[1];
  }

  return $return;
}

$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value&arg2=value2#anchor';

var_dump( extractGETParams($url) );
```

On Codepad.org: http://codepad.org/mHXnOYlc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_str()](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-str.php), and then access the variable $id.